# How can I optimize my XSL file?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to learn to format XSL more efficiently.  I can tell by the definition of duplicate variables and nearly identical templates that I did not create this efficiently at all.  How could I have formed this better?

```
Here is my XSL: you can see all of it at http://wwwstage.samford.edu/calendar/ADCCancel.xsl
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:r25="http://www.collegenet.com/r25"
xmlns:r25fn="http://www.collegenet.com/r25/functions"
xmlns:xl="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
version="2.0">
<xsl:output
  method="xml"
  encoding="UTF-8"
  version="1.0"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="pubdate">
        <xsl:value-of select="r25:events/@pubdate"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:element name="CALENDAR_ENTERPRISE">
        <xsl:attribute name="Created">
            <xsl:value-of select="$pubdate"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:element name="TIMEZONE">
            <xsl:attribute name="type">group</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:element name="GMTOffset">
                <xsl:attribute name="type">text</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:text>-6</xsl:text>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>           
        <xsl:apply-templates select="r25:events/r25:event/r25:profile">
            <xsl:sort select="r25:init_start_dt"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:element>

</xsl:template>



<xsl:template match="r25:profile">
    <xsl:variable name="evtname" select="../r25:event_name"/>
    <xsl:variable name="evttitle" select="../r25:event_title"/>
    <xsl:variable name="refno" select="../r25:event_locator"/>
    <xsl:variable name="profilename" select="r25:profile_name"/>
    <xsl:variable name="desc" select="../r25:event_text[r25:text_type_id=1]/r25:text"/>
    <xsl:variable name="relweb" select="../r25:custom_attribute[r25:attribute_id=-1]/r25:attribute_value"/>
    <xsl:variable name="eventImage" select="../r25:custom_attribute[r25:attribute_id=-4]/r25:attribute_value"/>
    <xsl:variable name="ticket" select="../r25:custom_attribute[r25:attribute_id=4]/r25:attribute_value"/>
    <xsl:variable name="flyer" select="../r25:custom_attribute[r25:attribute_id=6]/r25:attribute_value"/>
    <xsl:variable name="contact" select="../r25:role[r25:role_id = -1]/r25:contact"/>
    <xsl:variable name="catsno" select="count(../r25:category)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="org" select="../r25:organization[r25:primary='T']/r25:organization_name"/>
    <xsl:variable name="created_dt" select="../r25:event_history[1]/r25:history_dt"/>
    <xsl:variable name="usetitle" select="../r25:custom_attribute[r25:attribute_id=6]/r25:attribute_value"/>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="r25:rec_type_id != 2">
            <xsl:call-template name="RecurringEvent">
                <xsl:with-param name="evtname" select="$evtname"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="evttitle" select="$evttitle"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="refno" select="$refno"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="profilename" select="$profilename"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="desc" select="$desc"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="relweb" select="$relweb"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="ticket" select="$ticket"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="flyer" select="$flyer"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="evtimg" select="$eventImage"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="contact" select="$contact"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="catsno" select="$catsno"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="org" select="$org"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="startdate" select="r25:init_start_dt"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="enddate" select="r25:init_end_dt"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="spaces" select="r25:reservation/r25:space_reservation"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="created" select="$created_dt"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="usetitle" select="$usetitle"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="r25:reservation">
                <xsl:with-param name="evtname" select="$evtname"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="evttitle" select="$evttitle"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="refno" select="$refno"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="profilename" select="$profilename"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="desc" select="$desc"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="relweb" select="$relweb"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="evtimg" select="$eventImage"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="ticket" select="$ticket"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="flyer" select="$flyer"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="contact" select="$contact"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="catsno" select="$catsno"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="org" select="$org"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="created" select="$created_dt"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="usetitle" select="$usetitle"/>
             </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template name="RecurringEvent">
    <!-- Setup variables for different parts of the XML for each event -->
    <xsl:param name="evtname"/>
    <xsl:param name="evttitle"/>
    <xsl:param name="refno"/>
    <xsl:param name="profilename"/>
    <xsl:param name="desc"/>
    <xsl:param name="relweb"/>
    <xsl:param name="ticket"/>
    <xsl:param name="flyer"/>
    <xsl:param name="evtimg"/>
    <xsl:param name="contact"/>
    <xsl:param name="catsno"/>
    <xsl:param name="org"/>
    <xsl:param name="startdate"/>
    <xsl:param name="laststartdate"/>
    <xsl:param name="enddate"/>
    <xsl:param name="spaces"/>
    <xsl:param name="created"/>
    <xsl:param name="usetitle"/>

XSL TO CREATE EVENTNODES
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="r25:reservation">
    <!-- Setup variables for different parts of the XML for each event -->
    <xsl:param name="evtname"/>
    <xsl:param name="evttitle"/>
    <xsl:param name="refno"/>
    <xsl:param name="profilename"/>
    <xsl:param name="desc"/>
    <xsl:param name="relweb"/>
    <xsl:param name="evtimg"/>
    <xsl:param name="ticket"/>
    <xsl:param name="flyer"/>
    <xsl:param name="contact"/>
    <xsl:param name="catsno"/>
    <xsl:param name="org"/>
    <xsl:param name="created"/>
    <xsl:variable name="startdate" select="r25:event_start_dt"/>
    <xsl:variable name="enddate" select="r25:event_end_dt"/>
    <xsl:variable name="spaces" select="r25:space_reservation"/>


  /// xsl to create Event Nodes
 </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="r25:category">
    <xsl:variable name="goodcategories">
            <!-- Only push marketing categories to the calendar. The list below represents their IDs -->
            <xsl:variable name="isinlist">
                <xsl:value-of select="index-of((31,32,33,35,43,46,101,104,105,106,107,108,125,125,127,128,129),number(r25:category_id))" />
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:if test="$isinlist != ''">
               <xsl:value-of select="concat(r25:category_name,'||')"/>
            </xsl:if>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="$goodcategories"/>  
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="r25:rec_type_id">       
<!-- This translates the R25 recurrence ID into something ADC understands based on http://knowledge25.collegenet.com/display/WSW/Profile+information-->
    <xsl:param name="code"/>
    <xsl:variable name="pattern" select="substring($code,1,2)"/>
    <xsl:element name="RecurType">
        <xsl:choose>        
<!--rec type of 0 means there are no recurrences.  it is just a one-off event -->
        <xsl:when test=". = 0">
            <xsl:text>One Time</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>        
<!--rec type of 2 means there are is a meeting pattern. the first 2 letters define the pattern. -->   
        <xsl:when test=". = 1">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="substring($pattern,1,1) = 'W'">
                    <xsl:text>Weekly</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring($pattern,2,1)"/>
                </xsl:when>                   
<!--Set if monthly--> 
                <xsl:when test="substring($pattern,1,1) = 'M'">
                    <xsl:text>Monthly by Date</xsl:text>
                    <!--Unlike the others, the monthly patterns list the number on the 3rd character -->
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring($code,3,1)"/>
                </xsl:when>                  
<!--Set if daily-->
                <xsl:when test="substring($pattern,1,1) = 'D'">
                    <xsl:text>Interval</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring($pattern,2,1)"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise></xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test=". = 2">
            <xsl:text>Custom</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:text>Otherwise</xsl:text>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:element>

    <xsl:element name="RecurEndDate">
        <xsl:attribute name="type">text</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:call-template name="parse-profile-code">
            <xsl:with-param name="ProfileCode" select="$code"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="return">Date</xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
 </xsl:element>

    <xsl:element name="RecurDays">
        <xsl:attribute name="type">text</xsl:attribute>
        <!-- The following if statement is to take into account the rule mentioned on pg 8 
        of the import guide stating this is only supposed to be used if the recur type is weekly -->
        <xsl:if test="substring($pattern,1,1) = 'W'">
        <xsl:call-template name="parse-profile-code">
            <xsl:with-param name="ProfileCode" select="$code"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="return">Days</xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="parse-profile-code">
    <xsl:param name="ProfileCode"/>
    <xsl:param name="return"/>
    <xsl:analyze-string select="$ProfileCode" regex="^([DWMY])([MDP]?)([0-9]*)\s?(.*)?">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:variable name="Rest">
                <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(4)"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="Until">
                <!-- Build the recur end date from the R25 profile code and store in a variable named until-->
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$return='Date'">
                        <xsl:analyze-string select="$Rest" regex="([0-9][0-9]*T[0-9]*([\-+][0-9]*|Z)?|#[0-9]*)">
                            <xsl:matching-substring>
                                <!--The profile code lacks the necessary dashes to perform the format dateTime function.  This inserts them in where needed. -->
                                <xsl:value-of select="substring(regex-group(1),1,4)"/>
                                <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
                                <xsl:value-of select="substring(regex-group(1),5,2)"/>
                                <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
                                <xsl:value-of select="substring(regex-group(1),7,2)"/>
                            </xsl:matching-substring>
                        </xsl:analyze-string>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="$return='Days'">
                        <xsl:analyze-string select="$Rest" regex="([0-9][0-9]*T[0-9]*([\-+][0-9]*|Z)?|#[0-9]*)">
                            <xsl:matching-substring>
                                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(regex-group(1))"/>
                            </xsl:matching-substring>
                        </xsl:analyze-string>
                    </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>

            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="Days">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="string-length($Until) = 0">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$Rest"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before($Rest,$Until))"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$return = 'Date'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="format-date($Until,'[M]/[D01]/[Y]')"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$return = 'Days'">
                    <xsl:call-template name="listdays">
                        <xsl:with-param name="daylist">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$Days"/>
                        </xsl:with-param>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>                
        </xsl:matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>   
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="listdays">
    <xsl:param name="daylist"/>
    <xsl:variable name="tokenizedDayList" select="tokenize($daylist,'\s+')"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$tokenizedDayList">
        <xsl:if test=". = 'MO'">Monday</xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test=". = 'TU'">Tuesday</xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test=". = 'WE'">Wednesday</xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test=". = 'TH'">Thursday</xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test=". = 'FR'">Friday</xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test=". = 'SA'">Saturday</xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test=". = 'SU'">Sunday</xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test=". != $tokenizedDayList[last()]">
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>            
    </xsl:for-each>




</xsl:template>
```

Here is a sample of the xml file being transformed: http://wwwstage.samford.edu/calendar/sampler25.xml

And here is a sample of the output I am producing: http://wwwstage.samford.edu/calendar/ADECancel.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Some tips to improve your coding:

(a) don't do this:

```
<xsl:variable name="pubdate">
    <xsl:value-of select="r25:events/@pubdate"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

when you can do this:

```
<xsl:variable name="pubdate" select="r25:events/@pubdate"/>
```

The latter is not only one line of code instead of three, it's also much more efficient because it doesn't involve constructing a new tree.

(b) don't do this:

```
<xsl:element name="CALENDAR_ENTERPRISE">
        <xsl:attribute name="Created">
            <xsl:value-of select="$pubdate"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
```

when you can do this:

```
<CALENDAR_ENTERPRISE Created="{$pubdate}">
```

In Saxon it won't make any performance difference, but it's much more readable.

(c) I can't see why you are passing all these parameters. The values are all accessible from the context node, so I don't see why the called template can't get the values it needs by navigating from the context node.